# regionprops with python sparse arrays

Tags: python, scipy, sparse-matrix, image-segmentation, scikit-image

I have a `label_image` (ie an array that associates each pixel of an image to a physical object. Zero is for the background, one of the first object (a car, an animal for example) etc... The array has dimension of dimension 46000-by-40000 and is of type `scipy.sparse.csr_matrix`

I want to calculate some stats, like centroids and area but `skimage.measure.regionprops` does not work with sparse arrays

Has anyone seen anything similar to `regionprops` that would take python sparse arrays please?

Comment: Wow! fwiw, I have never seen something like this, so you *might* be out of luck, and have to implement it yourself. The only *incomplete* thing I can think of is this PR to dask-image: https://github.com/dask/dask-image/pull/97, would would require you to create a dense but out-of-core array of your image. But then you'd still need to figure out the regionprops part yourself. Distributed regionprops is something on my radar but it'll be a few months before I get back to it. sparse... That wasn't even on my radar. =\

Comment: Another thing that might be useful is zarr (https://zarr.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which lets you have dense-but-compressed in-memory arrays. I suspect that would be very effective for your volume, but then you'd still need something like that dask-image function to pull out all the bits.

Comment: Check out https://github.com/jrussell25/dask-regionprops#about which applies skimage region props to dask in a smart way